# google-play-scraper presents different results for count=1 and count=x

Tags: python, google-play

I'm having trouble understanding google-play-scraper and I was hoping you could help me.

I'm testing getting all of the reviews for a Playstore app and I encountered an issue where I can only get one French review out of the two that exist.

Having count=1 returns me one of them and if I change the sort it will provide me the other one.

If I change to count=2, or any other number, it won't give me any results.

The other reviews are in Portuguese, both from Portugal and Brazil if you fancy checking how that's working as well.

```
from google_play_scraper import Sort, reviews

app_id = "com.gudnest.mobile"

countries = ['FR']
languages = ['fr']

all_reviews = []

for country in countries:
    for lang in languages:
        print(f"Fetching reviews for {country} in {lang}")

        # Initialize the continuation token as None
        continuation_token = None

        while True:
            # Fetch reviews with the current continuation token
            result, continuation_token = reviews(
                app_id,
                lang=lang,
                country=country,
                filter_score_with=None,  # Default filter score
                sort=Sort.NEWEST,  # Default sort order
                count=1,  # Adjust the count as needed
                continuation_token=continuation_token,
            )

            print(f"Length is {len(result)} and token is {continuation_token.token}")

            # Append the reviews to the cumulative list
            all_reviews.extend(result)

            # Check if there's a continuation token to fetch more reviews
            if continuation_token.token is None:
                break
    
print(all_reviews)
```